# "Der Zug endet in Nürnberg und fährt nach kurzem Aufenthalt nach Bamberg weiter"

Tags: phrase, meaning-in-context

Die Deutsche Bahn ist in ihrem Sprachgebrauch zum Teil schon sehr merkwürdig.

Du sitzt in einem Zug aus München und willst nach Bamberg. Kurz vor Nürnberg hörst du die Durchsage:

> Dieser Zug endet in Nürnberg und fährt
>   nach kurzem Aufenthalt nach Bamberg weiter.

Was bedeutet das? Und vor allem: **Musst du etwas tun?**

**Edit:** wenn ich mich richtig erinnere, waren das Regional-Express-Züge. Besonders unverständlich war, dass an manchen Tagen am Bahnsteig "Nürnberg" und an anderen Tagen "Bamberg" angegeben war.

Comment: War das in einem Regionalexpress oder in einer S-Bahn?

Comment: Auch beliebt: "Dieser Zug hält nicht überall." - Bahndeutsch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das bedeutet ziemlich sicher, daß die Fahrt (die [Zugnummer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugnummer)) formell in Nürnberg endet, derselbe Zug aber unter einer anderen Zugnummer nach Bamberg weiterfährt.

Das interessiert den Kunden natürlich überhaupt nicht, aber formell ist es eben korrekt (und oft relevant, wenn es um die Gültigkeit von Tickets geht usw.)

> Musst du etwas tun?

Nein. Diese Meldung bedeutet aus meiner 15-jährigen fast täglichen Bahnfahrerfahrung  **immer**, daß man im Zug sitzenbleiben kann. Wenn es etwas zu tun gibt (z.B. von einem Zugteil in den anderen wechseln wegen Trennung), wird dies immer angesagt.

Eine ähnlich lustige Meldung (aber mit dem umgekehrten Hintergrund) gibt es in Köln Hbf mit dem berühmten "Zug kann jederzeit nach Köln-Deutz abfahren". Das wird [hier](http://forum.zusi.de/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=9576) schön erklärt.

**Edit:** Für die S1 Schwandorf-Bamberg (falls Du in dieser saßt) ist Nürnberg laut dem [Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahnstrecke_N%C3%BCrnberg%E2%80%93Bamberg) in der Tat Endbahnhof, selbst wenn die gleiche Bahn *mit der gleichen Zugnummer* sofort Richtung Bamberg weiterfährt. Warum, kann nur die Deutsche Bahn beantworten :)

Comment: Frage ist natürlich auch, ob man etwas tun muss, wenn man nach Bamberg fahren will: Zwischendurch aussteigen? Wohl kaum.

Comment: @The nein, die Meldung heißt definitiv, daß man sitzenbleiben kann.

Comment: Ich weiß es nicht, aber für mich bedeutet dies, dass die Bahn davon ausgeht, dass Fahrgäste aussteigen können, da wenn der Zug weiterfährt sie wieder zurück in die Richtung fahren aus der sie kommen. Mit anderen Worten: Ja, du musst etwas tun und zwar aussteigen, es sei denn Du fährst im Zug bewusst hin und her.

Comment: "Das interessiert den Kunden natürlich überhaupt nicht" - da möchte ich widersprechen. Wenn ich eine Fahrkarte mit zwei Zügen drauf habe, der zweite von Nürnberg nach Bamberg, ist es für mich durchaus relevant zu wissen, dass ich genau im aktuellen Zug sitzen bleiben kann.

Comment: "selbst wenn die gleiche Bahn mit der gleichen Zugnummer sofort Richtung Bamberg weiterfährt" - in der aktuellen Version des Wikipedia-Artikels finde ich keine Erwähnung von "Endbahnhof" mehr, aber im Allgemeinen kennt man bei S-Bahnen die Zugnummer als Normalmensch doch meist gar nicht. Sicher, dass sie sich nicht "unterwegs" ändert? ("S1" ist *nicht* die Zugnummer.)

Answer (score 5):

Eine Vermutung: Das Wort *Zug* wird hier wahrscheinlich im Bahnjargon oder in der Fachsprache der Bahn verwendet.

Ein Zug erhält für seine Strecke (München-Nürnberg) eine bestimmte Nummer und Personal. Hat er dann sein Ziel erreicht hat (in diesem Fall Nürnberg), bekommt er neues Personal und wahrscheinlich eine andere Zugnummer. Aus praktischen Gründen bleiben die Lok und die Zusammenstellung der Garnituren jedoch erhalten. Aus der Sicht des Fahrgasts ist der Zug derselbe geblieben, aus Sicht der Bahn handelt es sich um einen neuen Zug.

Die Aussage ist für Normalsterbliche natürlich sehr verwirrend.

Answer (score 0):

Meiner Meinung nach ist das Verwirrende, dass der Begriff *Zug* hier in verschiedenen Bedeutungen verwendet wird.

Im Teil

> Dieser Zug endet in Nürnberg

wird *Zug* als Fachbegriff im Sinne von *Zug**fahrt*** verwendet, wie schon mehrfach geschrieben wurde, dass heißt als Bezeichnung für eine Zusammenstellung mehrerer Wagen, die eine bestimmte Fahrt unter einer bestimmten Nummer unternehmen. Diese Fahrt endet fahrplanmäßig in Nürnberg.

Im Teil

> und fährt nach kurzem Aufenthalt nach Bamberg weiter.

jedoch bezieht sich *Zug* offenbar nur auf die physische Komponente, also die verbundenen Wagen, die anschließend als andere *Zugfahrt* im ersteren Sinne nach Bamberg verkehren.

Als Fahrgast muss man jedenfalls nichts machen, übersetzt heißt die Durchsage also:

> Die fahrplanmäßige Zugfahrt nach Nürnberg endet hier, anschließend wird dieselbe Garnitur aus Lok und Wagen eine weitere Zugfahrt nach Bamberg unternehmen.

Comment: Ich bezweifle ein wenig, dass hier zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen vorliegen. Dass ein Zug "endet" und anschließend "weiterfährt", widerspricht sich ja nicht - was wäre denn die alternative Interpretation? Dass ein Zug, wenn er "endet", nie mehr weiterfährt oder verschrottet wird?

Comment: Wie definierst du denn Zug? *Enden* heißt ja nicht *anhalten*, sondern *aufhören*, und bezieht sich auf die Zug*fahrt*. Eine Zugfahrt beginnt und endet, ein Zug fährt los und hält an. Das sind die zwei Bedeutungen, die hier vermischt wurden: Die Zug**fahrt** endete, und der Zug fuhr anschließend weiter. Im Bahnbetrieb heißt eben beides kurz *Zug*.